# Web server attacked by redirected traffic

Tags: regex, apache, debian, firewall, fail2ban

Currently my webserver which is only used for my personal site is being overloaded with redirected traffic. I'm trying to use fail2ban to reduce the load but my Regex is not that great.

Below is a sample of my access log

```
142.4.113.210 - - [03/Sep/2014:12:40:39 +0200] "GET http://ads.sonital.com/ttj?id=3139842&size=300x250&cb=[CACHEBUSTER] HTTP/1.0" 404 522 "http://www.seversname.com/?p=1387" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/3.0.195.1 Safari/532.0"
184.105.160.169 - - [03/Sep/2014:12:40:39 +0200] "GET http://ads.sonital.com/ttj?id=3397183&size=300x250&cb=[CACHEBUSTER] HTTP/1.0" 404 522 "http://www.ibusinessstatistics.com/?p=1003" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; AOL 9.0; Windows NT 6.0; 001|Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.0.04506; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)"
142.4.118.60 - - [03/Sep/2014:12:40:40 +0200] "GET http://ads.sonital.com/ttj?id=3139831&size=300x250&cb=[CACHEBUSTER] HTTP/1.0" 404 522 "http://www.selceticon.com/?p=892" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; Avant Browser; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.0.04506; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; InfoPath.2)"
142.4.113.215 - - [03/Sep/2014:12:40:40 +0200] "GET http://ads.sonital.com/ttj?id=3139842&size=300x250&cb=[CACHEBUSTER] HTTP/1.0" 404 522 "http://www.seversname.com/?p=1262" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; AOL 9.5; AOLBuild 4337.42; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
192.74.240.178 - - [03/Sep/2014:12:40:40 +0200] "GET http://ads.sonital.com/ttj?id=3342345&size=300x250&cb=[CACHEBUSTER] HTTP/1.0" 404 522 "http://www.ifinanceblog.com/?p=1615" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; AOL 9.6; AOLBuild 4340.12; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
```

And here is my error log

```
[Wed Sep 03 12:47:59 2014] [error] [client 198.40.51.25] File does not exist: /var/www/ttj, referer: http://www.seversname.com/?p=1309
[Wed Sep 03 12:47:59 2014] [error] [client 192.74.252.17] File does not exist: /var/www/ttj, referer: http://www.caridly.com/?p=1393
[Wed Sep 03 12:47:59 2014] [error] [client 198.40.62.198] File does not exist: /var/www/ttj, referer: http://www.selceticon.com/?p=1281
[Wed Sep 03 12:48:00 2014] [error] [client 198.40.62.237] File does not exist: /var/www/ttj, referer: http://www.selceticon.com/?p=1001
[Wed Sep 03 12:48:00 2014] [error] [client 148.163.24.107] File does not exist: /var/www/tt, referer: http://www.elanceapc.com/?p=1515
[Wed Sep 03 12:48:00 2014] [error] [client 137.175.105.79] File does not exist: /var/www/tt, referer: http://www.elanceapc.com/?p=1522
```

Here is the code from my filter which is pointed to the error log.

```
before = apache-common.conf
failregex = ^\[\w{1,3}.\w{1,3}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} \d{1,4}. \[error] \[client.<HOST>].File does not exist: ~*
ignoreregex =
```

Here is the code from the jail.local

```
[apache-nohome]
enabled   = true
port      = http,https
filter    = apache-nohome
logpath   = /var/log/apache*/*error.log
maxretry  = 1
findtime = 604800
bantime = 604800
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It now has reached a point that i'm running out of memory on my server: fork: Cannot allocate memory" error

Answer (score 0):

Well according to the [DOC](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Filters), fail2ban has a great tool: fail2ban-regex

root@server:/#fail2ban-regex 'Wed Sep 03 12:48:00 2014] [error] [client 148.163.24.107] File does not exist: /var/www/tt, referer: http://www.elanceapc.com/?p=1515' '[error] [client.].File does not exist: ~*'

```
Running tests
=============

Use regex line : \[error] \[client.<HOST>\].File does not exist: ~*
Use single line: Wed Sep 03 12:48:00 2014] [error] [client 148.163....


Results
=======

Failregex
|- Regular expressions:
|  [1] \[error] \[client.<HOST>\].File does not exist: ~*
|
`- Number of matches:
   [1] 1 match(es)

Ignoreregex
|- Regular expressions:
|
`- Number of matches:

Summary
=======

Addresses found:
[1]
    148.163.24.107 (Wed Sep 03 12:48:00 2014)

Date template hits:
2 hit(s): MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): WEEKDAY MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second Year
0 hit(s): WEEKDAY MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Year/Month/Day Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Day/Month/Year Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Day/Month/Year Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Day/MONTH/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Month/Day/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Year-Month-Day Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Day-MONTH-Year Hour:Minute:Second[.Millisecond]
0 hit(s): Day-Month-Year Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): TAI64N
0 hit(s): Epoch
0 hit(s): ISO 8601
0 hit(s): Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): <Month/Day/Year@Hour:Minute:Second>

Success, the total number of match is 1
```

So the correct regex would be `\[error] \[client.<HOST>\].File does not exist: ~*`

I never used fail2ban before...